# Javascript convert unix date to ddmmyy format

Tags: javascript

I have a chart that's giving me this date:

```
1577612800000
```

I need to convert it to "ddmmyy" format

I found this:

```
var timestamp = 1577612800000;                 
var date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
```

But it has no format.

How can I do this with format ddmmyy ?

Comment: what is this format ?? random number ?

Comment: I'd suggest using moment.js to do any sort of date conversions. Reason is, right now you'd need to do `date.getDate()`, `date.getMonth()+1`, and `date.getYear()` then manually format it.

Comment: @Mahi it's the Unix timestamp for 29th of December 2019

Comment: 2019 not 29 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get values from [Date](https://www.google.com/search?q=Date&oq=Date&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i59l3j69i60&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) object and generate the string by concatenation.

```js
var timestamp = 1577612800000;
var date = new Date(timestamp);
console.log(
  date.getDate() + '' + (date.getMonth()+1) + date.getFullYear()
)
```

Comment: I need the year in 2 digits though

Comment: @MarkcceEros :  use `date.getYear()`

Comment: But now the result has 7 digits?

Comment: @MarkcceEros : you need to subtract 100

Comment: @MarkcceEros : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear#Description

Comment: @MarkcceEros : `(date.getYear() - 100)`

Comment: @MarkcceEros :  or `date.getYear().toString().slice(-2)`